# Maximum value of non adjacent elements in a circular list

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Given that :

- You have a circular linked L with nodes N1,N2,...N10,N1
- Each node is characterized by a tuple (L,P) where L is the value for **not picking** the node and P is the value for **picking** the node
- If you pick a node then you can't pick it's neighbors say if you pick N1 then you can't pick N2,N10

How can one determine the maximum value that can be acquired ?

I know it is DP and that it is similar to the maximum sum of non - adjacent elements in a list but the fact that it's a cycle confuses me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: suppose there are *k* nodes, you can get rid of the cycle by comparing two solutions:

1. taking n<sub>1</sub> and solving the non-cyclic problem for nodes n<sub>3</sub>, n<sub>4</sub>, …, n<sub>k-1</sub>, or
2. not taking n<sub>1</sub> and solving the non-cyclic problem for nodes n<sub>2</sub>, n<sub>3</sub>, …, n<sub>k</sub>.

The best of these two solutions gives the optimum for the cyclic problem.